# How do I find out the additional 3 effects of ingredients?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Every ingredient for things you can make in Skyrim has 4 effects. The first one can be discovered by simply eating the ingredient.

I know that the first and second one together can also be found out if you have the right perk for it in the alchemy tree.

But how do I get to the other effects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Trial and error by brewing potions. If you match 2 ingredients that have an effect in common, you produce a potion/poison of that effect. There is also the Experimenter perk in the alchemy tree which lets you see more effects by just eating the ingredients.

Comment: You can also get your hands on potion recipes, telling you about an effective combination without requiring trial and error.

Comment: @Joren Unfortunately, I don't believe the recipes will update your character's knowledge base directly.

Comment: @Iszi: That is true, but it does tell you exactly what to do, which is the next best thing.

Answer (score 3):

[This webapp will help you figure out available combinations based on the ingredients you have.](http://bitemyapp.com/potions/)
this is an APP i use to figure out what ingrediants do what and what potion is worth more since leveling in alchemy is determined by this. i'm a new user just trying to share
a resource since i haven't seen one like it listed on here...

Comment: Not found, the link is dead

Answer (score 1):

I use this link and have learned all four uses of an ingredient. You can also level up your alchemy and put your perks to learn the first 3 uses of an ingredient.
If you want potions with more than one effect example: Damage health damage magic. Go to the potion ingredients you want to mix. Choose 2 ingredients for your first vial and then look at the second potion you want to have the extra effect. Make sure that one of the ingredients listed for the first part of the potion is in the second additive for a potion.

http://m.ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim/Potions

Answer (score 0):

These combinations helped me a lot to discover most of ingredient effects:

> Easy - Vendor Ingredients Only
>
> > 1. Creep Cluster + Dwarven Oil + Taproot
> > 2. Elves Ear + Fire Salts + White Cap
> > 3. Cyrodilic Spadetail + Jazbay Grapes + Salt Pile
> > 4. Dragon's Tongue + Fly Amanita + Scaly Pholiota
> > 5. Slaughterfish Egg + Slaughterfish Scales + Thistle Branch
> > 6. Abecean Longfin + Bleeding Crown + Ice Wraith Teeth
> > 7. Bee + Giant Lichen + Mora Tapinella
> > 8. Bleeding Crown + Tundra Cotton + Void Salts
> > 9. Blisterwort + Blue Mountain Flower + Hagraven Feathers
> > 10. Blue Butterfly Wing + Bone Meal + Snowberries
> > 11. Daedra Heart + Giant's Toe + Wheat
> > 12. Falmer Ear + Fly Amanita + Troll Fat
> > 13. Juniper Berries + Moon Sugar + Vampire Dust
> > 14. Canis Root + Falmer Ear + Spider Egg
> > 15. Chaurus Eggs + Lavender + Nirnroot
> > 16. Blisterwort + Hagraven Claw + Spriggan Sap
> > 17. Butterfly Wing + Hagraven Claw + Wheat
> > 18. Giant's Toe + River Betty + Salt Pile
> > 19. Bone Meal + Deathbell + Giant Lichen
> > 20. Canis Root + Imp Stool + Mora Tapinella
> > 21. Daedra Heart + Rock Warbler Egg + Scaly Pholiota
> > 22. Hagraven Claw + Lavender + White Cap
> > 23. Histcarp + Nordic Barnacle + Red Mountain Flower
> > 24. Ice Wraith Teeth + Luna Moth Wing + Vampire Dust
> > 25. Cyrodilic Spadetail + Daedra Heart + Nirnroot
> > 26. Dwarven Oil + Garlic + Slaughterfish Egg
> > 27. Canis Root + Juniper Berries + Rock Warbler Egg
> > 28. Beehive Husk + Ectoplasm
> > 29. Falmer Ear + Namira's Rot

> Medium - Some Hunting Required
>
> > 30. Charred Skeever Hide + Eye of Sabre Cat + Mudcrab Chitin
> > 31. Glowing Mushroom + Pine Thrush Egg + Sabre Cat Tooth
> > 32. Blue Dartwing + Imp Stool + Swamp Fungal Pod
> > 33. Frost Mirriam + Orange Dartwing + Purple Mountain Flower
> > 34. Honeycomb + Silverside Perch + Skeever Tail
> > 35. Beehive Husk + Canis Root + Hawk Feathers
> > 36. Beehive Husk + Grass Pod + Red Mountain Flower
> > 37. Chaurus Eggs + Deathbell + Large Antlers
> > 38. Blue Dartwing + Namira's Rot + Nordic Barnacle
> > 39. Blue Mountain Flower + Glow Dust + Glowing Mushroom
> > 40. Abecean Longfin + Butterfly Wing + Small Antlers
> > 41. Chicken's Egg + Histcarp + Large Antlers
> > 42. Beehive Husk + Garlic + Luna Moth Wing
> > 43. Eye of Sabre Cat + Moon Sugar + Silverside Perch
> > 44. Honeycomb + Pearl + Thistle Branch
> > 45. Hawk Beak + Mudcrab Chitin + Snowberries
> > 46. Orange Dartwing + Slaughterfish Scales + Small Pearl

> Hard - Possible Effort Required
>
> > 47. Bear Claws + Small Pearl + Hanging Moss
> > 48. Frost Salts + Hawk Beak + Pearl
> > 49. Briar Heart + Ectoplasm + Human Flesh
> > 50. Chicken's Egg + Nightshade + Wisp Wrappings
> > 51. Creep Cluster + Torchbug Thorax + Wisp Wrappings
> > 52. Abecean Longfin + Bee + Powdered Mammoth Tusk
> > 53. Cyrodilic Spadetail + Frost Salts + Powdered Mammoth Tusk
> > 54. Hagraven Feathers + Human Heart + Void Salts
> > 55. Human Flesh + Purple Mountain Flower + Torchbug Thorax
> > 56. Human Heart + River Betty + Spriggan Sap

[Source](https://skyrimforums.org/sf/threads/discover-all-ingredient-effects-by-brewing-56-potions.18638/)