# Is it possible to learn all effects of an ingredient by eating it without the use of perks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am aware that there is a perk that reveals more effects when ingredients are eaten. Is it possible to learn different effects by eating the same ingredient multiple times?

Comment: Nope. http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy

Comment: In case the reference no longer exists: the answer is that there is a perk that allows more ingredients to be discovered through eating.

Comment: This seems like a question already asked (with an up-voted and accepted answer) here:

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34982/how-do-i-find-out-the-additional-3-effects-of-ingredients?rq=1

But also intentionally rhetorical without offering any new or useful information.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @JimThio Because it's a relatively poor question with very little research or effort put into it. We appreciate questions that show at least a little initiative on this site.

Comment: Little research? What makes you think I did little research? Show me a web reference showing that yes you can only know 1 ingredients by eating it.

Comment: @JimThio - the claim of "little research" is made likely because the answer is readily available on numerous sites, one of which is...here, five years ago, when it was a relevant question during the initial release of the title and not at a re-release (where the answer to this question would be inferred as "no": http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34982/how-do-i-find-out-the-additional-3-effects-of-ingredients?rq=1.

Answer (score 5):

No, without perks you will only ever reveal the first of an ingredient's four effects by eating it.

Comment: references to confirm?

Comment: @JimThio 410 hours in the game.

Comment: How do you know you've been playing for 410 hours.